# dynamic names in R (subsetting and merging)

Tags: r, dynamic, merge

I would like to dynamically create some data frames using the subsetting fuction. For the moment:

```
bucket = c("branch", "rich")
sector_filter = c("test==1","test==2")

for (i in 1:length(bucket))
{
eval(parse(text = paste0(bucket[i], "=subset(data, ", sector_filter[i],")")))
}
```

Is there a way to do it properly, this works but is not very elegant. Same questions with merge. How can I avoid this

```
for (i in 1:length(bucket))
{
bucket[i] = merge(bucket[i], var, by = "qtr", all.x = T)
}
```

Comment: The element in the `bucket` are strings.  You need the value.  Perhaps `mget(bucket)` and then do the `filter`.  Please show a small reproducible example for 'branch' and 'rich'

Comment: For subsetting: `df.list <- list(branch, rich) ;  output <- list() ; for (i in 1:2){
  output[[i]] <- lapply(df.list, function(x){subset(x, subset, test=i)})
}`

Comment: thanks both, it works :)

Comment: Typo in last comment, it should be `output[[i]] <- lapply(df.list, subset, test==i)`